# Filter array by value in last column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-filter

I have matrix like this:

```
m1 = 
[1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1]
[1, 3, 5, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 3, 7, 3, 1, 1]
```

I need to filter it tp get value 1 in the last column. So result should be like this:

```
filter_array = 
[1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1]
[1, 3, 5, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 3, 7, 3, 1, 1]
```

My current code is:

```
m1 = np.array  ##see array above
filter_array = [ ]  ## the filtered array will be stored here. raw by raw 
for raw in m1: 
    if raw[-1] ==1:
        filter_array = filter_array.append(raw[:])
```

My code gives me back an empty array. I've must missed something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
filtered = m1[m1[:, -1] == 1]
```

**Note**: Your original code did not work because you were assigning the return value of `append()` method to the `filter_array`. Since the return value when append to a list is successful is `None`, you lose your original list after reassigning it to `None`.
To get your code working, simply do `filter_array.append(row[:])` as this mutates the list in place. Simply appending `row` also works.

Comment: In addition to showing a better way to do it, it would help if you explained why the original code didn't work.

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks for pointing it out. Updated my answer with explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`filter_array.append(raw[:])` returns nothing. Its `NoneType`.
So you cannot append row to a `NoneType` object the second time it executes in the loop.

Your corrected loop should be:

```
filter_array = []
for raw in m1: 
    if raw[-1] ==1:
        filter_array.append(raw[:])
print(filter_array)
```

Or better you could use list comprehension and boolean indexing like below:

```
 filter_array = m1[[True if arr[-1] == 1 else False for arr in m1]]
```